# What is a Mutated Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*This is in the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Mutated Word™.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Mutated Words™ | Not Mutated Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| BRASH | CALM |
| CROWN | TIARA |
| DINNER | LUNCH |
| FEEL | SENSE |
| LADDER | STAIR |
| SEAT | STOOL |
| SUPPER | BREAKFAST |
| THINK | REACT |
| WHOSE | WHOM |

In case you want it in CSV:

```
Mutated Words™,Not Mutated Words™
BRASH,CALM
CROWN,TIARA
DINNER,LUNCH
FEEL,SENSE
LADDER,STAIR
SEAT,STOOL
SUPPER,BREAKFAST
THINK,REACT
WHOSE,WHOM
```

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Mutated Word™ without relying on the other words.

These are not the only examples of Mutated Words™, many more exist.

Comment: That chair is bugging me

Comment: Actually, now that I look at it, chair is a mutated word.  I will update.

Comment: Is stool a mutated word also?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess would be that

> a mutated word is a word that is created by combining 2 other words with some cross over (specifically the second word starts with the second last letter of the first word)

Explanations:

> BRA and RASH --> BRASH
>  CROW and OWN --> CROWN
>  DIN and INNER --> DINNER
>  FEE and EEL --> FEEL
>  LAD and ADDER --> LADDER
>  SEA and EAT --> SEAT
>  SUP and UPPER --> SUPPER
>  THIN and INK --> THINK
>  WHO and HOSE --> WHOSE

Similarly a non mutated word is any word that doesn't fit that condition

> Ex. BREAKFAST --> BREAK and FAST do not cross over

Comment: @MikeQ AIR also works for that though. Either way, it fits for all the ones in the actual question

Comment: Yeah, basically any two words that share two letters.  So, CHAIR IS CHAI and AIR.  Your explanation of the "second last letter" was spot on.

Answer (score 3):

Can be reduced letter by letter to a single letter word leaving an (albeit archaic or obscure) word at each stage.

E.g. brash->rash->ash->as->a
     think->hink->ink->in->I

But obviously not the answer: whom->who->ho->o stool->tool->too->to->o

Comment: How do you do that with FEEL? (Also, welcome to Puzzling!)

Comment: @Deusovi Feel-eel-el-e where el is a unit of measurement and E is the 3rd degree of the C-major scale

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work with both sets of answers, but I like this reasoning.  Would probably make a great "What is a Word" puzzle down the road once people forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

A Mutated Word™ is a word that:

> remain a word after removing the first letter

Example:

> BRASH -> RASH 
>  CROWN -> ROWN 
> DINNER -> INNER

Not Mutated:

> CALM -> ALM 
>  TIARA -> IARA

Comment: Stool -> tool. That one doesn't work

Comment: And Calm -> Alm works.  But Whom -> Hom,Think -> Hink, and Crown -> Rown do not.